# How to get the file name from RepeaterCommandEventArgs in asp.net (WebForm) Repeater control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to get the image file name upon clicking the Delete button on my UI so I can pass it to C# to remove the file from a folder.

My aspx code is:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterImages" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepeaterImages_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Width="80px" Text="Delete" CommandName="delete" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My C# is:

```
protected void RepeaterCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem itemToRemove = e.Item;
    String sessionItemToRemove = itemToRemove.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("%c", sessionItemToRemove);
    Session.Remove(sessionItemToRemove);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WHat you are trying to do only works in the `ItemDataBound` event, not the `ItemCommand` event. But you can get the value like this

```
protected void RepeaterCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = e.Item.FindControl("Image") as Image;
    Session.Remove(img.ImageUrl);
}
```

Or use the `CommandArgument` of the Button

```
protected void RepeaterCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Session.Remove(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
}
```

For the above to work the Buttons needs the following

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
```